# Unable to generate the chart from HighCharts

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, highcharts

I use below code to generate a bar chart for my system using HighCharts. The problem is that the chart is not generating.The sql query is working and I feel like the problem is with the json_encode What I have done wrong?

```
<div id="container" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>

<?php

 $data = array();
 $label=array();
$result=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM job_output group by Line_Number");
     foreach ($result as $value) :
     $data[] = $value['O_Total'];
     $label[] = $value['Line_Number'];
     array_push($data,$label);
    endforeach;


   ?>
   <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
             renderTo: 'container',
             type  :'bar'
                    },
             title: {
                    text: 'Production'
                     },
             xAxis: {
             categories: [<?php echo json_encode('$label')?>]
                    },
             series: [{
            data: [<?php echo json_encode('$data')?>],
            pointStart: 0,

                   }]
               });

        });

         </script>
```

Comment: what is the error you getting? check js console.

Comment: console does not show any error. Only the chart title is showing

Comment: Add your json data here , so that it could be figure out

Comment: all the labels and data have integer values. I am new to programming and it would be big help

Comment: take a reference from my last answer of related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33833711/create-highcharts-column-type-from-json/33844144#33844144

Comment: $(function () {
                                    var jsonData = [{"total":'$data',"line":'$label'}];
                                     var categoryData= [];
                                    var seriesData= [];
                                    $.each(jsonData, function(i,item){
                                 seriesData.push(jsonData[i].total);
                                 categoryData.push(jsonData[i].line);
                                  console.log("seriesData"+JSON.stringify(seriesData));
                                 });

Comment: still have the problem of adding data to jsonData from the database . What's the problem of the above code?  json is not getting data from $data

Comment: while iterating you should push your items in data array under the foreach loop

Comment: Did you meant like this?foreach ($result as $value) :
                                                     $data.array_push($value['O_Total']);
                                                    $label.array_push($value['Line_Number']);
                                                  
                                                    endforeach;

Comment: $data.push(value) like this

Comment: still it's not working. I did like this  $data.push($value['O_Total']);
                                                    $label.push($value['Line_Number']);

Comment: How your json looks like, including data inside.

Comment: This is what i did earlier <?php echo json_encode('$data')?>

Comment: I mean what returns your json_encode. print your json please

Comment: the label shows $label

Comment: I know, but what prints $label. I mean please paste your output json like {data:[1,2,3]} etc.

Comment: for the label it should be like [1,2,3..] and data will also have [50,100..] and they are dynamic integer values